# Start animation on button press not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my recent project i need a Door to open if the user is in front of it and has pressed "e".

This is the Code for the Button:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Animator Door; // In the editor, give a reference to your door. It     must have an Animator script for this to work

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
        if (c.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            //Text = "E to interact!" 

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                print("´Test");
                GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("OnPress"); // The button's animator goes to "pressed" state
                Door.SetTrigger("Open");  // The door's animator goes to "open" state
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Animator looks like this:
[image: Animator]

The Transition from Idle to Open:
[image]

The Button has the Door attached to it:
[image: Door with Animator]

So i got two issues here, the first is - With the above Code nothing happens if i press E. No Error, No Action, whatsoever.
If i delete the `Input.GetKeyDown("e")` and make the Button-Mesh to a Trigger and run in it, it says

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animator' attached to the
>   "Button" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You
>   probably need to add a Animator to the game object "Button". Or your
>   script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

If you need more Information, just let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please select the transition and show it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your approach to the interaction is wrong. First of all, On trigger enter will work only once. That is when you enter the trigger. So it won't take the Keypress event. You will have to move the code in [OnTriggerStay(Collider col)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay.html) where it will constantly be called. There if it takes any key event, then it will fire up. That will solve your problem 1.

As for the second problem, I'm pretty sure you copy paste this code from somewhere else. Only the canvas UI Button has animator state. Your button is Normal mesh and not the UI one. So setting the state button in that code won't work, ie

`GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("OnPress"); // The button's animator goes to "pressed" state`

Unless you are using the Canvas Button that script does not work. And the error description already mentioned the error you Button Mesh Does not have an animator. Try commenting the line and see how it works.

Edit:

I went through your transition your code should be

```
door.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("OnPress");
```

and not

```
GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("OnPress");
```

As it is trying to call the OnPress state of door animator. If any trouble comes comment below with more info. Sorry did not notice this first.

Comment: Okay, so the Code works now! Yes, i copy and pasted that from a previous question i asked. That code is from @Toaster.

However, i now get "Parameter 'Open' does not exist." as an Error. Could you help me out with that?

Comment: I think there should be still the issue Door.SetTrigger("Open"); you cannot play a clip like that. That is just to set the trigger from parameters. Mostly will give error. You might have to rework your Animator. Try checking with animator again. That is wrong approach to animator trigger.

Comment: Your animator is not properly setup. Do set it again. If you want to play a specific clip the you just have to say animatorObject.Play("Clipname");

Comment: Easy method i would recommend  here is create four separate clips. Idle_Close, Closing, Idle_Open, Opening, Clip. Then set their transition like Closing->Idle_Close and  Opening->Idle_Open. Then just say 
animatorobj.Play("Closing") and animatorobj.Play("Opening"). which will tranition the states directly without parameter variable. By default i will keep Idle_close as default animation.

Comment: Thanks o both of you! Your answers worked flawless :)